# Can't make Parcel + Babel 7 + Jest work together

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, parceljs

I have a problem with making Parcel, Jest and Babel work with the same `.babelrc`

Parcel version: 1.11.0

Jest version: 24.0.0

Node: v10.5.0

Platform: Win 10

`.babelrc`

```
{
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "corejs": 2
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "test": {
        }
    },
}
```

If I move the `plugins` section to the root of the JSON it works correctly with the web app, however Parcel or Babel for some reason can't recognize the development env even if I set it in the command line.

If run the tests without the environment setup (having the `env` as above) then I get

```
 ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _Promise from "@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/promise";
```

with Jest.

Probably the test setup wouldn't get recognized either, it just works without the `babel/plugin-transform-runtime`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this `.babelrc` solved it:

```
{
    "env": {
        "production": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "corejs": 2
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
                    {
                        "corejs": 2
                    }
                ]
            ]
        },
        "test": {
            "plugins": [
            ]
        }
    },
}
```